# How can I load historical stock indices data in my script without yahoo or google finance using pandas_datareader?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, google-finance

Sorry for my *noobish* question as I'm trying to use Python for my finance class in grad school.

I am currently stuck trying to load historical stock indices of ***DOW JONES, S&P 500 and NASDAQ***. Sadly, Google Finance is useless with stock indices so I need help circumventing this obstacle.

Here is the the line of my code that handles the loading process:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticker = ['^DJI', '^INX', '^IXIC']

ind_data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in ticker:
    ind_data[i] = web.DataReader(i, data_source='google', start='2000-1-1')['Close']
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [quandl](https://www.quandl.com/search?query=). It is a third party package you will need to install.

```
pip install quandl
```

Go to their website, make an account and get an api key. Then [search the site](https://www.quandl.com/search?query=) to find the right code to type in for each query.

You can pass the `quandl.get` function a variety of different parameters to get exactly what you need. The below retrieves the [dow jones industrial average](https://www.quandl.com/data/BCB/UDJIAD1-Dow-Jones-Industrial-Average) and outputs it as a pandas dataframe.

```
quandl.get("BCB/UDJIAD1")
```

Output

```
...
2016-04-06  17716.05
2016-04-07  17541.96
2016-04-08  17576.96
2016-04-11  17556.41
2016-04-12  17721.25
2016-04-13  17908.28
2016-04-14  17926.43
2016-04-15  17897.46
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, Quandl doesn't have free data access for the indices I need

Comment: @Mysterio What are all the indices you need. It has the three you mentioned above.

Comment: can you please help me find them. Noob with quandl